Появление меню при наведении на три точки HTML/CSS
При наведении на .task-dots должно появляться меню .dots с одной кнопкой "Редактировать", но по какой - то причине у меня это не получается.


body {
  background-color: #202020;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

form {
  padding: 15px 15px 0 15px;
}

label {
  display: flex;
}

.daytasks-task {
  width: 250px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  font-family: Inter;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: rgb(179, 178, 178);
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: none;
  border: 1px solid #424242;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.daytasks-task:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px;
}

.real-checkbox {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}

.custom-checkbox {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: transparent;
  border: 1px solid #424242;
  border-radius: 10px;
  vertical-align: sub;
  margin-right: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.custom-checkbox::before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  background-image: url('imgs/checkmark3.png');
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0);
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.real-checkbox:checked+.custom-checkbox::before {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
}

.label-text {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 1% 0 0 1%;
}

.real-checkbox:checked+.label-text {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

.task-dots {
  background: #202020;
  background-image: url(imgs/3dots.png);
  background-size: cover;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: -5px 1px 9px 2px #202020;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

.dots {
  width: 10%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: #1d1d1d;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 20px 0 0 85px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: none;
}

.task-dots:hover .dots {
  display: block;
}

.dots-edit {
  width: 95.5%;
  height: 35px;
  background-color: transparent;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 6px 6px 6px 10px;
  font-family: Inter;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-align: left;
  color: #c4c4c4;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dots-edit::before {
  content: "";
  background-image: url(/project/css/imgs/edit.png);
  background-size: cover;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: sub;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.dots-edit:hover {
  background-color: #2b2b2b;
}

.daytasks-task:hover .task-dots {
  opacity: 1;
  box-shadow: -10px 1px 9px 2px #202020;
}
<div class="daytasks-task">
  <form>
    <label>
            <input type="checkbox" class="real-checkbox" id="real1" onclick="checkBoxLineThrough1()">
            <span class="custom-checkbox"></span>
            <div class="label-text" id="label-text1">1</div>
            <a>
                <div class="task-dots" id="dots"></div>
            </a>
            <div class="dots" id="dotsmenu">
                <button class="dots-edit">Редактировать</button>
            </div>
        </label>
  </form>
</div>



